# Nth Ngonal Numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, integer

Most of us are probably familiar with the concept of triangular and square numbers.  However, there are also pentagonal numbers, hexagonal numbers, septagonal numbers, octagonal numbers, etc.  The Nth Nagonal number is defined as the Nth number of the sequence formed with a polygon of N sides.  Obviously, N >= 3, as there are no 2 or 1 sided closed shapes.  The first few Nth Ngonal numbers are 0, 1, 2, 6, 16, 35, 66, 112, 176, 261, 370, 506, 672, 871....  This is sequence [A060354](http://oeis.org/A060354) in the OEIS.

### Your Task:

Write a program or function that, when given an integer n as input, outputs/returns the Nth Nagonal number.

### Input:

An integer N between 3 and 10^6.

### Output:

The Nth Nagonal number where N is the input.

### Test Case:

```
25 -> 6925
35 -> 19670
40 -> 29680
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score in bytes wins!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99688/polygonal-numbers)

Comment: It would not hurt to add a direct precise definition.

Answer (score 13):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 1 byte

```
ℙ
```

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//1HLzP//jUwB)

Comment: A built-in for this?  Really?  Obviously less obscure than I'd thought.

Comment: @Gryphon It's existed for ages.

Comment: You mean the built-in?

Comment: @Gryphon Yeah. It's existed since May.

Comment: Weird.  I'd have thought there were a lot of more common sequences to give built-ins to first.

Comment: @Gryphon At that point, there were a lot of challenges for polygonal numbers, so I just added a bunch to Neim :P

Comment: Got it.  That was before I joined the site, so, ya know, before my time.

Comment: This seems to be a built-in for calculating the `a`th `b`-gonal number, which gets both its parameters autofilled with the only argument given.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Neil*

```
<ÐP+>;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f5vCEAG076///TQwA)

**Explanation**

```
<        # push input-1
 Ð       # triplicate
  P      # product of stack
   +     # add input
    >    # increment
     ;   # divide by 2
```

Comment: `<Dn*+>;` also works for 7 bytes.

Comment: @Neil: Thanks! A modified version of that saved me a byte :)

Comment: Can't you do `<3m` instead of `<ÐP`?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: Sure, but it's the same amount of bytes.

Comment: @Emigna Just asked to be sure.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
c3×3+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/Z@PB0Y@3///@bGAAA)

Computes [choose(n, 3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) × 3 + n.

This translates quite readily to 05AB1E:

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
3c3*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fONlYS/v/fxMDAA)

Comment: Umm, why do you have a ``f=\`` in a Jelly submission header? :P

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>34</s> 28 bytes

```powershell
param($n)$n*($n*$n-3*$n+4)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPUyVPC0hpqeTpGgMJbRNNfaP///@bGAAA)

Closed-form solution golfed from the OEIS page. Used FOIL for another 6 byte savings.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
´U+³ z Ä
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=tFUrsyB6IMQ=&input=MzU=)

- 1 byte saved thanks to [ETH](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)

---

### Explanation

Decrement (`´`) the input (`U`), add the input cubed (`³`) to that, floor divide by 2 (`z`) and add 1 (`Ä`).

Comment: There are about a bazillion ways to rewrite this in 9 bytes, but it's tough to find an 8-byte solution... oh, here's one I think should work: `´U+³ z Ä`

Comment: Nice one, @ETHproductions; got distracted by work while trying to crunch it down.

Comment: @ETHproductions Nice one, that's tricky...another one would be `´U+³+2 z`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: or `ÄÄ` instead of `+2`.

Comment: 7 bytes: `à3 *3+U` or `U+3*Uà3` (credit goes partly to Lynn)... Quite sure it can be rearranged to save more bytes.

Comment: Nice one, @Mr.Xcoder. You should post that yourself, it's different enough to mine.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 6 bytes

```
t3^+he
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=t3%5E%2Bhe&input=35&warnings=0&hex=0)

```
t      - Decrement.
 3^    - Raise to the power of 3.
   +   - Add the input.
    h  - Increment.
     e - Floor Halve.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 23 bytes

```python
lambda n:(~-n)**3-~n>>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSqNON09TS8tYty7Pzs7wf0FRZl6JQpqGkammgq2tgoKZpZGpDoTPBZMzhsgZWpqZG@hA@HA5EwOwnJGlmQVYDsj/DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
t3Xn3*+
```

Luis Mendo's suggestion, which is a little clearer.

```
    (implicit input)
t                         duplicate
 3Xn                      n choose 3
    3*                    multiply by 3
      +                   add
(implicit output)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8Q4Is9YS/v/f1MA)

```
t:3XNn+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8TKOMIvT/v/f1MA)

Both solutions port [Lynn's algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145012/67312)

```
(implicit input)
t                         duplicate
 :                        range (1...n)
  3XN                     push 3, compute all 3-combinations of the range
     n                    number ( equal to 3*choose(n,3) )
      +                   add
(implicit output)
```

Comment: Perhaps a little simpler: `t3Xn3*+`

Comment: huh, I swear I looked for `Xn` and didn't see it. I'm not convinced I know how to read documentation...

Comment: Documentation could be clearer :-) It assumes you more or less know the equivalent Matlab functions. In this case, if you search for _combinations_ of _`nchoosek`_ in [Suever's server](http://matl.suever.net/) it gives both functions as results

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

- Saved one byte thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil); golfed `>>1` to `/2`.

```python
lambda n:n*(n*n-3*n+4)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk9LI08rT9dYK0/bRFPf6H9BUWZeiUKahpGppoKtrYKCmaWRKRdM0BgiaGhpZm4AFzQxAAsaWZpZGPwHAA)

Comment: Can you not use `/2` instead of `>>1`?

Comment: @Neil True, true.

Comment: @Neil It was an artifact from back when there had been a sum that needed division.

Answer (score 2):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 11 bytes

```
*Ha+-Sa*3a4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P9fyyNRWzc4Ucs40eT/fxMDAA)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

```
f=(n,k=n)=>k<2|n<3?k:f(n-1,k)+f(3,k-1)
```

Recursion FTW (or maybe only for seventh...)

Comment: Or you could port the closed form solution for 17 bytes...

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 14 bytes

shorter than built-in!!!

```
(#^2-3#+4)#/2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X0M5zkjXWFnbRFNZ30jtf0BRZl6JgkN6tIlB7P//AA)

and 3 bytes shorter with Martin Ender's help

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), <s>20</s> 17 bytes

Saved 3 bytes porting [Emigna's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144992/67312).

```
Iu(:^\:**p+u@O,2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/9@zVMMqLsZKS6tAu9TBX8dI8/9/I1MA)

```
    I u
    ( :
^ \ : * * p + u
@ O , 2 ) . . .
    . .
    . .
```

#### original answer:

```
Iu-2^\:*p*qu@O,2+p*:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/9@zVNcoLsZKq0CrsNTBX8dIu0DL6v9/I1MA)

Expands to the cube

```
    I u
    - 2
^ \ : * p * q u
@ O , 2 + p * :
    . .
    . .
```

which implements the `(n*(n-2)^2+n^2)/2` approach.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 3 bytes

```
DÆ¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/3@Vw26El//8bm/4HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 20 bytes

```
#~PolygonalNumber~#&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
+*3.cQ3
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%2a3.cQ3&input=35&debug=0)**

Uses [Lynn's algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145012/59487).

Answer (score 1):

## dc, 13 bytes

```
dd2-2^*r2^+2/
```

A fairly straightforward implementation of the first formula listed on the [OEIS page](http://oeis.org/A060354).

```
# Commands           # Stack Tracker (tm)
# Begin with input   # n
d                    # n n
d                    # n n n
2-                   # n-2 n n
2^                   # (n-2)^2 n n
*                    # n*(n-2)^2 n
r                    # n n*(n-2)^2
2^                   # n^2 n*(n-2)^2
+                    # n*(n-2)^2+n^2
2/                   # (n*(n-2)^2+n^2)/2 # matches first formula
# End with output on stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
à3 *3+U
```

**[Try it here!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=4DMgKjMrVQ==&input=MzU=)**

First, it was a comment on Shaggy's answer, but they told me I should post it myself.

Comment: Only noticing this now - +1.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
ÅU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cGvo//9GpgA)

#### How?

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

## [HOPS](https://akc.is/hops/), 17 bytes

```
{n*(n*n-3*n+4)/2}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kI7-geG20kq5uQVFqsq2ZgVLsgqWlJWm6Fhur87Q08rTydI218rRNNPWNaiHiUOkFUBoA)

Using the generating function given on OEIS by [R. J. Mathar](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:R._J._Mathar):

## [HOPS](https://akc.is/hops/), 23 bytes

```
x*(1-2*x+4*x^2)/(1-x)^4
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kI7-geG20kq5uQVFqsq2ZgVLsgqWlJWm6FtsrtDQMdY20KrRNtCrijDT1gbwKzTgTiCxU0QIoDQA)

Or using the exponential generating function given on OEIS by [Paul Barry](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Paul_Barry):

## [HOPS](https://akc.is/hops/), 24 bytes

```
(exp(x)*(x+x^3/2)).*{n!}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kI7-geG20kq5uQVFqsq2ZgVLsgqWlJWm6Fjs0UisKNCo0tTQqtCvijPWNNDX1tKrzFGsh0lBVC6A0AA)

-3 bytes thanks to alephalpha

Comment: -3 bytes for the last one: `(exp(x)*(x+x^3/2)).*{n!}`.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 23 bytes

```
{x*(((x*x)-(3*x))+4)%2}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6qu0NLQ0KjQqtDU1TAGkpraJpqqRrVcXGnqioaGAIf0B3U=)

Having to add parenthesis because K parses from right-to-left.

Comment: "_Having to add parenthesis because K parses from right-to-left._" - you don't have to add all of them

Comment: for instance the `(` `)` around `3*x` are unnecessary, and you can avoid more pairs by rewriting things in equivalent ways

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
’*3+‘H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw0wtY@1HDTM8/v//b2QKAA)

Uses Emigna's algorithm inspired by Neil.

Comment: I think you'll find that the `<Dn*+>;` comment was mine...

Comment: I'm using his modification, but I'll add you as well.

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents 0](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents/tree/cquents-0), 16 bytes

```
#|1:A(AA-3A+4)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X7nG0MpRw9FR19hR20RT3@j/fyNTAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 18 bytes

```java
n->n*(n*n-3*n+4)/2
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hU/LDoIwELzzFXtsMVQDeDL6B3LhaDzUUk2RLoQWjDF8e13QO8k@MruzM9lajjJpO4119Qyqkc7BWRr8RAAGve7vUmkoZrgMQLG5Ij/QZKKkKADhCAGTE8YMY0yyGDc536bhENG6G26NUeC89NTG1lRgyYGVvjf4uFxB8p/87AuWpFC/FsAWF4Dy7by2oh286OjGN8isQKFYuudrlGydku/4/50pfAE)

The approach used by most other answers is the shortest in Java. For funsies I also ported two other answers:

Port of [Mr. Xcoder's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145002/52210) (**29 bytes**):

```java
n->(int)Math.pow(n-1,3)-~n>>1
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hU/NDoIwDL7zFD1uiSwieiLyBnDhaDzMMXXIuoUNiDH46jjQu0l/8rVf@7UNH3hsrMSmfsyi5c5BwRW@IgCFXnZXLiSUC1wLIMgSkWahMgUPVgLCEWaM86VHC@7vzJqRYJxsUhq/Mc@TOYsC0/aXVglwnvuQBqNq0EGMVL5TeDudgdOv0nIC6LAV5bgCsgoCVE/npWam98yGGd8i0QyZILsD/UdJ/1P2W/r7bJo/)

Port of [Lynn's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145012/52210) (with manual calculation of `a choose b`) (**76 bytes**):

```java
n->c(n,3)*3+nint c(int t,int c){return t<c?0:c==t|c==0?1:c(--t,c-1)+c(t,c);}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hVDLboNADLzzFXPcbVhCSnsJpfmCcsmx6mHjbFpS8CIwqaI0304XWqnHSH6MrbE19tGerPGt4@P@c6Ta9j1ebMWXCKhYXHew5FBO5dwAqSmyzkPnGjxYCUaBkc0zKY4zfZctOMoDf7lE6QWt7QT@APlw2J3FGfIDS/S/TeIZ60vnZOgY8kSbdE1FId8hpJvVmpQxEpNZ6QWpAHR@HYF22NUVoRcrIZ18tUcTtKutdBW/v77B6l/h00Vogkh2X3OhZv3A9tyLaxI/SNKGGalZNQknpO4f9S1KdpvykOq/R13HHw)